# $f(s) \approx \dfrac{1}{s}$. Where $f(s) = a - \dfrac{k}{b + is} $.

Tags: limits

$f(s) \approx g(s)$ if $\lim_{s \to \infty}\dfrac{f(s)}{g(s)} \neq 0$.  Let $a, k,b > 0$ and $f(s) = a - \dfrac{k}{b + is} $. Why
$$f(s) \approx \dfrac{1}{s} \ \ \text{as} \ \  s \to \infty$$

Note that
$$
f(s) = a - \dfrac{k}{b + is}  = \dfrac{(ab - k) + ias }{b + is},
$$
then
$$
\lim_{s \to \infty}\dfrac{f(s)}{1/s}  = \lim_{s \to \infty}\dfrac{s[(ab - k) + ias ]}{b + is} = \lim_{s \to \infty}\dfrac{[(ab - k) + ias ]}{\frac{b}{s} + i} = \infty
$$
I can't :(. And I know $\lim_{s \to \infty} f(s) = a$?

Comment: You are right, the exercise is wrong. $f(s)\approx 1,$ not $\frac1s.$

Comment: @AnneBauval Thank you very much